# ANTL4 Throws NullPointerException during parsing process

Tags: java, php, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I wrote a simple PHP parser code using this grammar: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/php

```
PhpLexer lexer = new PhpLexer(new ANTLRInputStream("echo 'aaa';"));
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
PhpParser parser = new PhpParser(tokens);
parser.consume();
```

Unfortunatelly it throws me an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.consume(Parser.java:584)
at com.test.Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

What is wrong? How to fix that?

I use ANTLR ver. 4.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`consume` is not a rule defined in the PHP grammar. Try this:

```java
parser.htmlDocument();
```

And to print the parse tree returned by `htmlDocument`:

```java
PhpLexer lexer = new PhpLexer(CharStreams.fromString("echo 'aaa';"));
PhpParser parser = new PhpParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
System.out.println(parser.htmlDocument().toStringTree(parser));
```

will print:

```
(htmlDocument (htmlElementOrPhpBlock (htmlElements (htmlElement echo 'aaa';))) <EOF>)
```

As you can see, it recognises your input as HTML. If you parse `<?php echo 'aaa';`, it will be recognised as PHP.